# How to properly import the ConfigServiceV2Client attribute from google-cloud-logging_v2 package in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-logging

I tried importing the ConfigServiceV2Client attribute as follows:

```
from google.cloud.logging_v2.services.config_service_v2 import ConfigServiceV2Client
```

And I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.logging_v2' has no attribute 'ConfigServiceV2Client'
```

How should I import it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error that you're getting it seems like you are missing some updated features, Install the google-cloud-logging package using pip as follows:

`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-logging`
based on the [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#install).

After installing it try importing it in to your project.

Or just uninstall the package:

`pip uninstall google-cloud-logging`

And then reinstall it.

Comment: thx. tried both, still doesn't work

Comment: Are you still getting the same error, or a different one?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Could you please add the following information: Python and pip versions, your environment, and all your import statements for this python file.